# Virtual member function disallow uniform initialization

Tags: c++

What is the reason why default initialization is possible with `RegBaseB` but not with `RegBaseA`:

```cpp
struct RegBaseA
{
    union {unsigned int value;};
    virtual unsigned int get_num_bits() const {return 32;};
};

struct RegBaseB
{
    union {unsigned int value;};
};

int main()
{
    // RegBaseA reg_a {10}; // not allowed
    RegBaseB reg_b {10};
}
```

Comment: my guess: aggregate initialization but adding a virtual function is making RegBaseA not an aggregate.

Comment: This has nothing to do with unions.

Comment: @user12002570 You're right: [coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bc16613c9bcc4a4) The anonymous union was somehow misleading... :-)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat Should we make the title more in line with the actual problem? Something like : *"Virtual function makes class non aggregate"* or something like that.

Comment: @user12002570 IMHO, the titles of duplicates are good enough to be triggered on google searches. The title might be good for people (like me) if on a wrong trace... ;-)

Comment: I agree. If I had searched the titles of the duplicates I would have not asked in the first place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`RegBaseB` is meeting the criterion for [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) but not `RegBaseA` which has a virtual function.

As you declared no special constructor, the compiler is trying an aggregate initialization, which is recognized as such here `RegBaseB reg_b {10};`.

Comment: Thank you. I now see in the documentation `An aggregate is one of the following types: [...] no virtual member functions`. Where could I look further why this is like this?

Answer (score -1):

The trivial initialization you have in `B` is able to be used because the compiler doesn't need to "do" anything to set it up.  There's no calculation or work in initializing values past writing the binary. `B` is very similar to old C-style "plain old data types" that are just fixed layouts in memory.

`A` does work because it requires a dynamic (read "runtime") dispatch table set up to figure out the correct function as it is declared `virtual`.